# gulp-If. How to check if js file contains specific property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, gulp, gulp-if

I am using gulp.js. But I want to add a condition that if request.debug = true; in any of my js file then gulp task should fail. I have found gulp-if and gulp-fail that I can use for this purpose but I don't know that how can I check the specific condition?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [gulp-contains](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-contains) module. If the condition provided to the contains function is true, an error is thrown.

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.src('src/**/*.js')
        .pipe(contains('request.debug = true;'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll definitely give it a try. One more thing, how can we then fail gulp task if this condition is true?

Comment: The module will throw an error as a default, so it will fail automatically. You could add a callback in case you need some additional error handling logic. Refer [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-contains#usage)

Comment: One more thing, is there anyway we can check that request.debug = true; is not commented?

Comment: It is possible to do so with a regular expression as there many ways to comment the code block. You can add your regex in the contains function argument.

Comment: Ok thanks and do you have any idea how can we trace the location where string found using gulp-contains?

Comment: The plugin doesn't return the specific position afaik. You can use the onFound callback which returns the file object where the match occurred. You could maybe read the file & find the specific index with that. It would be better if you could ask a new question on SO in case of more specifics.

Comment: I have asked a new question regarding this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51303941/how-can-i-extract-filename-from-gulp-contains-callback
Can you answer that question?